# How to use MongoDB 3.4 in Angular 2 Web App?

Tags: mongodb, angular, database

Actually, I trying to use MongoDB 3.4 in Angular 2 but not able to use it. Can anyone please share to me basic ways! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you can use Express.js to interact with MongoDB, and angular 2 will interact with Express.js.

Angular 2 App --> Express.js --> MongoDB.

Express.js can help you to connect MongoDB it can return JSON data which you can use within Angular 2 App.

here is basic guide to MEAN stack development https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli